# Getting list of sub-keys for a given key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

How do I create a function to get a list of all the subkeys within a dictionary for a given key.

```
Data = {
            'Andrew': {
                'Country': 'Australia',
                'Age': '20',
                
          
            },
            'Mary': {
                'Country': 'Australia',
                'Age': '25',
                'Gender': 'Female',
                
            },
  }
```

For a given key e.g Andrew or Mary I'd like to know the keys present. So if I ask for Andrew:
It gives [Country, Age] and Mary is [Country,Age,Gender]

Comment: I tried:
    def list_keys(self, key: str):

        all_keys = []
        for k in self.__final:
            all_keys.append(k)
            for k1 in self.__final[key]:
                all_keys.append(k1)
        return all_keys

Comment: Please post the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: I recommend [Getting started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to do via function. here you can make something like this

```
def get_subkeys(dictionary, key):
    if key in dictionary:
        return list(dictionary[key].keys())
    else:
        return []
```

**USAGE:**

```
data = {
    'Andrew': {
        'Country': 'Australia',
        'Age': '20',
    },
    'Mary': {
        'Country': 'Australia',
        'Age': '25',
        'Gender': 'Female',
    },
}

print(get_subkeys(data, 'Andrew'))  # Output: ['Country', 'Age']
print(get_subkeys(data, 'Mary'))    # Output: ['Country', 'Age', 'Gender']
print(get_subkeys(data, 'John'))    # Output: []
```

Comment: you're over complicating it a little bit:   `list(data.get('Andrew',[]))` will do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar has the right answer:

```
>>> list(Data['Andrew'].keys())
['Country', 'Age']
>>> list(Data['Mary'].keys())
['Country', 'Age', 'Gender']
```

Comment: the .keys() are not really necessary. `list(Data['Andrew'])` will also do.